# How to change footer content from single page that will apply for all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a footer for my website and have at most 50 pages in it. Consider my code

```
<div id="footer">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now If I am asked to add "contact us" option in the footer content, I need to go to all pages and have to add the "contact us" option. It is kind of irritating and time consuming.
There must be option to change the footer content from single page. 
Please help me in this issue. If there is any jquery code to achieve this it would be more grateful to me.

Comment: Learn about serverside includes.

Answer (score 1):

Go for Include file

```
 <div id="footer">
 <!--#include virtual="footer.html" -->  //your menu in this file
 </div>
```

And have a look at [Server side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) before start coding.

Comment: This still requires one to change each individual document.

Comment: @MCL If he changes in that one place.It changes in all places where ever he included.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.append()` in jquery. as:

```
$("#footer ul").append('<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>');
```